# QFileInfo seems not getting the folder type all the time

Tags: c++, qt, qfileinfo

I'm using `QFileInfo` when trying to implement a Drag and Drop, Strange things is that sometime the information is correct and other not when checking the same path.

Below is the code :

```
void MyTreeWidget::CopyFilesFromLocal(QStringList pathList, QTreeWidgetItem* item)
{
    QString fileelt;
    uint32_t Folder_id = INVALID;

    PulsTreeWidgetItem* myItem = dynamic_cast<MyTreeWidgetItem*>(item);

    uint32_t destination_id = myItem->mtp_item_id;

    item->setExpanded(true);
    qDebug() << "**************************************";
    qDebug() << "Send to device Start";
    qDebug() << "Start of Loop to copy files";

    foreach(fileelt, pathList)
    {
        char *txt = NULL;
        qDebug() << "elt to be analyzed: " << fileelt;
        txt = strdup(m_device.convertQStr2char(fileelt));
        qDebug() << "elt converted to char*: " << txt;

        QFileInfo fileInfo(txt);
        qDebug() << "QFileInfo: " << fileInfo.absoluteFilePath();

        qDebug() << "QFileInfo: " << fileInfo.absolutePath();

        if(fileInfo.isDir())
        {
            QStringList tmpfolderlist;
            QString tmpfoldername = NULL;
```

I'm trying to move a folder with some contents. the first element of the `pathlist` is the folder itself.

`fileInfo.isDir` is equal to true or false even if I'm trying to move the same folder.

Only things I notice :

```
fileelt(string):  "/Users/seb/Pictures/Photos/20131124 - SchoolClassPhoto/"
txt (char*):  /Users/seb/Pictures/Photos/20131124 - SchoolClassPhoto
```

`fileelt` is an extract of the `pathlist` and txt just a `str` to `char*` conversion and `QFileInfo` only take `char*`. by the way, the `"/"` is missing at the end after the string to `char*` convert.

The function to convert `str` to `char*` is :

```
char *PulsDeviceMngr::convertQStr2char(QString str) {
    return const_cast<char*>(std::string( str.toUtf8().constData() ).c_str());
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no surprise that you get random results. Notice that `convertQStr2char` returns pointer into temporary char table (`c_str()`) from temporary (!) string variable. This is very, very wrong. This data is just rubbish outside `convertQStr2char`.

Comment: Thanks I have removed the convertQStr2char and replace it by a simple function to avoid temporary allocation,